# Document provider extension does not update code changes in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a working project with document provider extension but it has a strange issue. When I change a code in DPE files and the press Run and select host app to launch newest code changes does not apply in the debug. However If I firstly Run my regular app (not extension. The app that contains extension in the embedded binaries section) and than extension newest code changes will apply and it will be possible to debug them.

Comment: What is the question itself? Also please read this section, when you'll be editing your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into this as well. The DocumentProviderExtension is packaged as part of the app itself. Xcode appears to interpret that as meaning you must build and run the main app in order to install the extension. Debugging (by selecting a Host App) appeared to work as expected, though.

I don't have a canonical source for this behavior, other than the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW8), which talks about the debug behavior.